# write into indexed array in pyopencl

Tags: python-2.7, opencl, pyopencl

hi i wrote this code in pyopencl to get sparse random vector but the problem is i can not write any value into indexed array what is the problem? output always zero!!

here is my code

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np
from pyopencl import array 
from pyopencl import clrandom

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,
        properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)

x=array.zeros(queue, 512, dtype=np.float32 )

indices = clrandom.rand(queue, 17 , dtype=np.int32 ,luxury=2, a=1 , b=512)

clrandom.RanluxGenerator(queue,luxury=0).fill_normal(x[indices], mu=0, sigma=1)

print x
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `x[indices]` is returning a copy instead of a view.

```
>>> import pyopencl as cl
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from pyopencl import array 
>>> from pyopencl import clrandom
>>> 
>>> ctx = cl.create_some_context()
>>> queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx,
...         properties=cl.command_queue_properties.PROFILING_ENABLE)
>>> 
>>> x=array.zeros(queue, 512, dtype=np.float32 )
>>> 
>>> indices = clrandom.rand(queue, 17 , dtype=np.int32 ,luxury=2, a=1 , b=512)
>>> x_cp = x[indices]
>>> x_cp
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
>>> clrandom.RanluxGenerator(queue,luxury=0).fill_normal(x_cp, mu=0, sigma=1)
>>> x_cp
array([ 1.16633689,  0.65845662,  1.97530341, -0.53728914,  1.38982224,
        1.47071588, -0.73042828,  1.29367638,  1.2390343 ,  2.89497447,
       -0.75589401,  0.04600764, -4.28992653,  0.50232059,  0.4881362 ,
        0.01112503, -0.46737072], dtype=float32)
>>> x[indices]
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

You could try the following:

1. Create a float32 array which has the same dimensions as your `indices` array, lets call it `tmp_random`.
2. Generate random numbers and store them in `tmp_random`
3. Write a kernel which takes `indices`, `tmp_random`, and `x` as arguments. Each thread reads one index out of `indices` and the according random number from `tmp_random` and stores it at the correct place in `x`.